# Er baut Radio Rebelde mit auf

Tags: morphology

The following citation is taken from the subtitles of a documentary on Che Guevara:

> Er baut Radio Rebelde mit auf.

What is the verb here?

There are two separable prefixes here, but I don't know the rules for such situations.  Is the infinitive *mitaufbauen* or *aufmitbauen*?

Also, does anyone know of a verb with three separable prefixes?

Comment: It's *mitaufbauen* or *mit aufbauen*. The prefixes are put in the same order as in the infinitive.

Comment: @Janka: Mitaufbauen ja wohl sicher nicht. Das gibt 's nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Ich vermute, dass Sie mit _das gibt's nicht_ meinen, es stehe nicht im Wörterbuch. Doch auch wenn _mitaufbauen_ während einer gewissen Beobachtungszeit nicht häufig genug verwendet worden ist, um in ein Wörterbuch aufgenommen zu werden, ist es ein regelkonform zusammengesetztes Verb.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: es sei denn, man schreibt es üblicherweise getrennt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb is *mitaufbauen*.

It's [English translation](https://www.dict.cc/?s=mitaufbauen) is

> to collaborate in building sth.

MyDict has some [example usages](https://www.mydict.com/Wort/mitaufbauen):

> 1. Sie werden das Dorf **mitaufbauen.** ( Quelle: Frankfurter Rundschau vom 26.07.2005）
> 2. Derweil haben sich zwei Sozialarbeiterinnen aus dem Jugendhaus Dudenhofen spontan bereit erklärt, eine Jügesheimer Jugendgruppe **mitaufbauen** zu helfen. ( Quelle: Frankfurter Rundschau 1992）
> 3. Dann dieser ehrenhafte Auftrag: Er soll in Minnesota (USA) ein Ordens-Gymnasium **mitaufbauen.** ( Quelle: BILD 1998）
> 4. Nicht nur, daß sie die Netze vor jedem Spiel **mitaufbauen** mußte, bevor sie den Schläger in die Hand nehmen konnte, hat sie gestört. ( Quelle: TAZ 1997）

I don't think that there are any German verbs with three separable prefixes. But *mitaufbauen* is an example for a verb with two separable prefixes, but they are rare. Here are some other examples. Most of then begin with *mit*:

- mitanfassen

  > Ich muss diese Kiste auf den LKW laden. Kannst du bitte mal **mitanfassen?**
  >   Peter hatte Klaus gebeten, **mitan*zu*fassen.**
  >   Klaus **fasste mit an** als der darum gebeten wurde.
  >   Klaus hat **mitan*ge*fasst**.
- miteinbauen

  > Wenn du das Gehäuse schon offen hast, kannst du da auch gleich die neue Speichererweiterung **miteinbauen?**
  >   Klaus **baute** die Speichererweiterung **mit ein.**
  >   Klaus wurde gebeten, die Speichererweiterung **mitein*zu*bauen.**
- voreinstellen

  > Kannst du mir helfen? Ich weiß nicht wie ich die Steuerung der Beleuchtung **voreinstellen** kann.
  >   Ich helfe dir, die Steuerung **vorein*zu*stellen**.
  >   Klaus **stellt** die Steuerung **vor ein.**
  >   Die Steuerung ist nun **vorein*ge*stellt.**

Comment: Vielleicht solltest du noch ein Wort dazu sagen, dass "mit aufbauen" häufiger getrennt als zusammen geschrieben wird. Der OP kann es in den üblichen Wörterbüchern vielleicht nicht finden, weil es deshalb dort nicht aufgeführt wird (damit sage ich aber nicht, dass es nicht richtig sei!).